# Laravel: How to avoid line-break in custom pagination?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination

I'm facing difficulty to solve an issue. I have made a custom pagination in my view page, but the pagination items get line breaks like following picture:

[image: A table with pagination. Each pagination item has it's own line and is preceded by a bullet]

I tried to avoid that by adding `<div>`, but couldn't get it solved.

I used the following line just after the end of my `</table>` tag.

```
{{ $managementReport->render()}}
```

Comment: are you using the laravel pagination?

Comment: Yes! But as I used raw query to get the data, I used `LengthAwarePaginator` with it. it's also there it in manual also..
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator

Comment: you could fix that by modifying the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination` or the pagination of your css

Comment: Check your css code for `<li><a>` style [default](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/default.blade.php). May your css code has given style for this code. P.S. Pagination use this structure.

Comment: @Beginner: You can't safely modify code inside the vendor directory. The next time you do a composer update, your change will get overwritten. So please avoid this like of suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your pagination code; it's likely just outputting an unordered list, in which every item is rendered in it's own line by default. You can easily override this behaviour with plain CSS using the following rule (I'm assuming you've added the `.pagination` class to your `ul`):

```
.pagination {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.pagination > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```